# What's the rule for transforming a verb into a noun if it ends in "ee"?

Tags: suffixes, agent-noun-suffix, agent-nouns

Usually a noun can be made from a verb by adding an -er as a suffix (to paint -> painter, to eat -> eater). What is the rule for verbs that already end with the letter "e", such as "see", "flee", "agree"? Do we:

- Add an "er" (agree -> agreeer)
- Add only an r (agree -> agreer), and if so, are they pronounced without the "er" sound?
- Do something else (Chrome's spellchecker underlined both of these)
- Or do they not exist at all (agree -> people who agree)?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add "r" to any verbs that end with "e", including "ee", to form a noun.

"agreer" is a legitimate word and I am sure your Chrome worked in a wrong way.

Comment: This rule also works for making adjectives into their comparative form.  But I can think of only one:  Free -> freer.  However, probably not carefree -> carefreer!

Answer (score 1):

See -> seer (but this has a special meaning -- a soothsayer)

Flee --> escapee (this one is counter-intuitive!)

Agree --> supporter

Alternatively:

Those who agree / he is in agreement

Comment: But, can't people flee without escaping? Also, it seems to me that you're evading the actual question.

Comment: I'll try a different one for flee -> refugee.  //  My answer (sorry, I should have been more explicit) is that I have not been able to discover a rule.  They are often irregular.  //  It was an interesting question!